# MTS N790 APN setting for GSM Network

Tags: settings, apn

I have MTS N790, it is a dual sim mobile one is CDMA and other is GSM .Now I have one mts CDMA sim and one Aircel GSM sim .Here I can not set access point setting for GSM sim. I can add new apn for CDMA but for GSM there is no option to set ApN.
Anyone can help?

[image: menu]

when I select 1St option

[image: 1st option]

and When I select 2nd option

[image: 2nd option]

Comment: Some dual SIM phones support only the primary SIMs mobile data. Have you checked that the phone supports mobile data through the second SIM also? I can't find proper specifications for that model.

Comment: @onik Means I cant use second sim Data connection.It doesn't seems logical.And how I can check that it supports mobile data through second sim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the phone specs on [MTS India](http://www.mtsindia.in/shop/duet-smartphone/), and seems like the second SIM supports only 2G voice + SMS, not data. This is because the phone is Dual SIM Dual Standby (DSDS), not Dual SIM Dual Active (DSDA or DSA), and there isn't a 3G GSM radio.

DSDS means that if you have a data connection or a call open, the other SIM is disabled. This would prevent the use of the primary SIM if there was an open data connection on the secondary SIM.

I'm not an expert on dual-SIM phones since they are not popular in my region, so there may be a way to get a 2G data connection over the GSM card, but it's not supported by the manufacturer.

Comment: When I disable CDMA sim even then I can't access the internet by second sim.

Comment: Then either the phone's hardware doesn't support data over GSM, or the manufacturer has disabled it in software. You would need to get more details about the radio chip to see if it's possible at all, and then find a custom ROM to enable GSM data in Android.